# Is there an explicit solution of $y_{n}$ in this binomial coefficient relation?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, random-variables, binomial-coefficients

In following, $x_{n}$ is a set of given numbers, n = 0, 1, 2, ...,
$y_{n}$ is defined by the following relation:

For example:

${\displaystyle {x_{1}=x_{0}y_{1} }}.$

${\displaystyle {x_{2}={\binom {1}{0}}x_{0}y_{2} + {\binom {1}{1}}x_{1}y_{1}  }}.$

${\displaystyle {x_{3}={\binom {2}{0}}x_{0}y_{3} + {\binom {2}{1}}x_{1}y_{2}  + {\binom {2}{2}}x_{2}y_{1}  }}.$

For simplicity, we can assume $x_{0} = 1$.

Q: Is there an explicit solution of $y_{n}$ in term of $x_{n}$ ?

Thank you.

Comment: Being off by an index it is the binomial transform.

Comment: @Phicar, can you explain a bit more on your comment ? I could not see why original relation is a binomial transform.

Answer (score 4):

This is an approach of just what i meant in the comments.

Suppose $$A(z)=\sum _{i = 0}^{\infty}x_i\frac{z^i}{i!},$$ and $$B(z)=\sum _{j=1}^{\infty}jy_j\frac{z^j}{j!}$$ then
$$A(z)B(z)=\sum _{n =0 }^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{n!}\left (\sum _{i =0}^{n-1}\binom{n}{i}x_i(n-i)y_{n-i}\right )=\sum _{n =0 }^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{(n-1)!}\left (\sum _{i =0}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{i}x_i(n-i)\frac{y_{n-i}}{n-i}\right )=z\sum _{n =1 }^{\infty}\frac{z^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}\left (\sum _{i =0}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{i}x_iy_{n-i}\right )=z\sum _{n =1 }^{\infty}\frac{z^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}x_n=zA'(z)$$
From there we get that $$B(z)=\frac{zA'(z)}{A(z)}$$ and so $$y_n=\frac{[z^{n-1}]ln(A(z))'}{n}.$$

Comment: thank you for the explanation. Is this some kind of binomial transform ? IDo we need do some conversion to interpret such relation as a binomial transform ?

Comment: Yes, binomial transform is just multiplying by exponential in the exponential generating function. If you know your sequence $x_i$ perhaps you can express formally its exponential function and compose. Perhaps you will find interesting the book "Combinatorial Species and Tree-like Structures".
Usually logarithm corresponds to understand your sequence as parts of a finer sequence. Take a look, for example, to Stirling numbers of the first kind.

Comment: Thank you again.  In your previous comments, you wrote: "If you know your sequence xi perhaps you can express formally its exponential function and compose." What do you mean "compose" ?  I took a look of Stirling numbers of the first kind on Wiki, what do you mean "Usually logarithm corresponds to understand your sequence as parts of a finer sequence" ? Is your comment related to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind#Relations_to_natural_logarithm_function ?

Comment: I meant compose it with logarithm. I meant that in the context of Species, the exponential is sequences without order. So logarithm is the inverse of that operation. For the stirling numbers i meant that check that the generating function is a logarithm, that is because permutations are factor into disjoint cycles. So, in some way, factorization of sequences and logarithm is connected(in the theory of species.)

Comment: It is still not clear to me, do $x_{n}, y_{n} $ or $x_{n}/n! ,  y_{n+1}/n!$ in the expression ${\displaystyle {x_{n}=\sum _{i = 0}^{n - 1}{\binom {n - 1}{i}}x_{i}y_{n -i} }}.$ form a binomial transform pair ?

Comment: Hi, ah yes is not like it is literally a binomial transform, what i meant is that there is an exponential convolution(That is a binomial transform when one of the series es $e^x$) notice that this part i am talking about is the LHS of the expression.